# Intel HD4000 driver 13.04 : can I calibrate color screen?

Tags: intel-graphics, colors

I've got a new laptop with an ugly blue tint (very painful for my eyes). I can calibrate the screen on windows 8, this is not perfect, but berable. I hesitate to go with the next ubuntu because I have not a nvidia card. Is there a config tool for Intel integrated graphic card to calibrate properly color ? Redshift or flu.x are not option (I want a yellowish tint, not a red).

Comment: Wait for a week when Ubuntu 13.04 is released. Until then it is off topic.

Comment: I answer to my own question : there is no easy way to calibrate color screen with an intel HD4000 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please put the answer as such (in the space for answer below) and accept it as correct. It will help others.